# How to change the request header limitation

Tags: node.js, express, header, request

I launched the node express on my localhost:3000..

**curl -H 'samlresponse:12323' -v http://localhost:3000 , returns data correctly.

but if I tried following...

**curl -H 'samlresponse:{here is the entire samlresponse, it's very long..almost 20k..}' -v http://localhost:3000**

The server always return "Empty reply from server", is there a way to passby or fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Source Code of node at github](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/http_parser/http_parser.h) says:

```
/* Maximium header size allowed. If the macro is not defined
 * before including this header then the default is used. To
 * change the maximum header size, define the macro in the build
 * environment (e.g. -DHTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE=<value>). To remove
 * the effective limit on the size of the header, define the macro
 * to a very large number (e.g. -DHTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE=0x7fffffff)
 */
#ifndef HTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE
# define HTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE (80*1024)
#endif
```

So, you probably need to rebuild node from source to surpass the limit of `80*1024`. But, personally I think that, it is large enough for a header, and you should re-evaulate whether your statergy is correct.

Comment: Thanks, you save my life

Comment: Cheers.. Gr8 it hepled